# Adding more statements in observable Map

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

Here I have method which works fine, able to subscribe the result.

```
fetchIncidentDetails(incidentId: number): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${AppUtils.INCIDENT_SEARCH}/${incidentId}/${+localStorage.getItem(AppUtils.PERSON_CODE)}`;
    let incident: Observable<IncidentReportModel>; 
    incident= this.http.get(url)
        .map(response => response.json().result)
        .catch(this.handleError);

    return incident;
}


public setIncidents(incidents: IncidentReportModel) {
    this.incidents = incidents;
}
```

If I add one more statement inside the map, not able to subscribe the response.
    I need to set the response value. How can I achieve this.

```
.map(response =>{response.json().result;  this.setIncidents(response.json().result)})})
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: when you add the extra statement you are no longer returning anything. You're basically changing the Observable<someResult> into Observable<void>.

Answer (score 0):

How I understand you want to do something like this

```
fetchIncidentDetails(incidentId: number): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${AppUtils.INCIDENT_SEARCH}/${incidentId}/${+localStorage.getItem(AppUtils.PERSON_CODE)}`;
    let incident: Observable<IncidentReportModel>; 
    incident= this.http.get(url)
        .map(response => {
            this.setIncidents(response.json().result)
            return response.json().result
             })
        .catch(this.handleError);

    return incident;
}
```

Read about how work [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in java scrippt

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { return expression; }
```